# Sample size and the test

Tags: self-study

I am doing an experiment to have an estimation of False Discovery Rate (FDR). Let we have 5000 samples from a normal population and we assume this is close enough to present the population. Next, we sample 10 observations from this population and run a test, $H_0:\mu_{pop}=\mu_{sample}$ versus $H_1:\mu_{pop}\neq\mu_{sample}$. we do this procedure for 3000 times. Obviously, there should not be any difference between two samples. As a result, the test should not be rejected more that $.005*5000$ given we test at $0.005$ level.

From this experiment, I observe that the FDR is estimated abnormally high. More interestingly, when I decrease sample from 10 to 1, the FDR is changed by a tiny value. Here is the R code,

```
n=5000
alpha=.05
x=rnorm(n)
for(i in 1:3000){
  s=sample(x,10)
  z[i] = (mean(x)-mean(s))/(sd(x)/sqrt(n))
}
sum(abs(z)>qnorm(1-alpha))/3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to calculate

```
z[i] <- (mean(x) - mean(s)) / (sd(x) / sqrt(n))
```

If you're trying to transform your sample mean's distribution to a standard normal distribution, you need to divide by the standard error of the sample mean,

```
z[i] <- (mean(s) - 0) / (1 / sqrt(length(s)))
```

Note that we're using the population mean, 0 and the population sd, 1, that you specified by default in your call to `rnorm()`.